# Python - How to update base class variable from derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, luigi

I'm new to OOP, but experienced in SQL. I'm writing a Luigi ETL task to generate reports.

I have a base class called Report, and 3 subclasses Report_Daily, Report_Weekly & Report_Monthly, which dynamically set the base class' SQL query's GROUP BY, so that the appropriate reports can be generated

```
#reports.py

class Report:
    report_sql = {'daily':'day', 'weekly':'firstdayofweek(day)', 'monthly':'firstdayofmonth(day)'}
    @property
    def report_type(self):
        return '' # To be instantiated by subclass
    sql = 'select '+report_sql[report_type]+' count(*) from employees group by '+report_sql[report_type]
    def run(self):
        #code that runs sql query

class ReportDaily(Report):
    report_type = 'Daily'

class ReportWeekly(Report):
    report_type = 'Weekly'

class ReportMonthly(Report):
    report_type = 'Monthly'
```

These 3 subclasses are then scheduled via Luigi & Chronos like

```
luigi --module etl.reports ReportDaily
luigi --module etl.reports ReportWeekly
luigi --module etl.reports ReportMonthly
```

But I'm getting 'Cannot concatenate string and property' error.
I tried setting report_type as a luigi parameter, but get similar error.
What is the proper design pattern to achieve this ?

Comment: Any reason you want report_type to be a property rather than  regular variable? Could you specify report_type = '' in the Report class and have that overwritten by the subclasses?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, if you do this:

```
class Report:
    report_sql = "bla"
```

`report_sql` will be a class variable. More info in [Python docs (Class and Instance Variables)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables). Because you want to change it in your classes it is better it be an instance variable (unique to each instance).

Also, I think the `Report` class needs to be an abstract base class (ABC). Check the docs for more info: [abc — Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Because technically, Abstract Classes shouldn't be instantiated, my `__init__` method has the `abstractmethod` decorator. As you can read, the `ReportDaily`, `ReportWeekly` and `ReportMonthly` classes call the constructor of the base class with the needed `report_type`.

I only keep the part related to the report type and the SQL query. This is my new code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Report(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, report_type):
        self.report_type = report_type
        self.sql = f'select {self.report_type} count(*) ' \
                   f'from employees ' \
                   f'group by {self.report_type}'

    def run(self):
        ...


class ReportDaily(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(report_type='Daily')


class ReportWeekly(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(report_type='Weekly')


class ReportMonthly(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(report_type='Monthly')


daily_report = ReportDaily()
print(daily_report.sql)
weekly_report = ReportWeekly()
print(weekly_report.sql)
monthly_report = ReportMonthly()
print(monthly_report.sql)
try:
    Report(report_type="dummy")
except TypeError:
    print("an abstract class cannot be instantiated!")
```

output:

```
select Daily count(*) from employees group by Daily
select Weekly count(*) from employees group by Weekly
select Monthly count(*) from employees group by Monthly
an abstract class cannot be instantiated!
```

Notes:

- I use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) for string formatting.
- [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is a good library for handling SQL in Python

Comment: Thanks. follow up : my base class itself derives from other classes, and somewhere in there, multiple keyword arguments are passed in to constructor. How should the derived class constructor account for it ? def __init__(self,**kwargs): super(**kwargs).__init__(report_type = 'monthly') ?

Comment: Put the `**kargs` inside `__init__` : `def __init__(self,**kwargs): super().__init__(report_type = 'monthly', **kwargs)` . More info of `super()` in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods